# JQuery onclick toggle on elements with diffrent id

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a table with a status column that displays a material icon play/pause depending on the status. Each row has a different ID, my problem is that I can't make the icon toggle onclick unless I use the ID directly in the code and this won't solve my issue. I want the code to handle the different Ids. I tried this.id, it works with an alert(), but in the code, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
                    <th>satatus</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ><i id="status-1" aria-hidden="true" medium="" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">pause_circle_outline</i></td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><i id="status-2" aria-hidden="true" medium="" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">play_circle_outline</i></td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>

 </table>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("i").click(function() {
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            $(this).attr("id").click(function(){
            //$("#status-1").click(function(){
                $(this).text($(this).text() == 'play_circle_outline' ? 'pause_circle_outline' : 'play_circle_outline');
            });
        });
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ids in this situation, just use a object what cause the event. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', "i", function() {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'play_circle_outline' ? 'pause_circle_outline' : 'play_circle_online');
        });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', "i", function() {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
                $(this).text($(this).text() == 'play_circle_outline' ? 'pause_circle_outline' : 'play_circle_outline');
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
                    <th>satatus</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ><i id="status-1" aria-hidden="true" medium="" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">pause_circle_online</i></td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><i id="status-2" aria-hidden="true" medium="" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">play_circle_outline</i></td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can identify the element that triggered the click, thanks to your code, but the toggle is acting weird, the icon disappears and it wasn't doing this before. Check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eb3varsp/1/

Comment: @CreekBarbara what disappeared?, i just checked and added my solution it works just fine. You just have to change every time the statuses of the rest elements.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. When you click on the play icon it changes to pause, but when you click on the pause icon it vanishes.

Comment: My bad, you just had play_circle_online instead of play_circle_outline which mad the icon disappear. I should have verified. Problem solved. Thank you.